# HTTP Request with PEM cert

Tags: api, http, ssl, pem, crystal-lang

Here my simple class to request thru HTTPS a webservice with PEM cert.

```
require [omit verbose]

class Api

    def initialize
        @ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::Context::Client.new
        @ctx.private_key = "/home/XXXXXX/development.pem"
        @ctx.verify_mode = LibSSL::VerifyMode::NONE
    end

    def customers
        response = HTTP::Client.get "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/api/customers", nil, nil, @ctx
        puts response.status_code
        puts response.body
        puts response.inspect
        nil
    end

end

Api.new.customers
```

But I only receive a **401 Authorization required** with **crystal run src/api.cr**.

Comment: Disabling verification shouldn't be necessary. If the CA is not in the system bundle, setting it in the context explicitly should be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set certificate_chain too.

Add this line in initialize method

```
@ctx.certificate_chain = "/home/XXXXXX/development.pem"
```